# XML generation using Nokogiri involving nested tags and namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

Using gem Nokogiri I'm trying to generate XML like:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
  <env:Envelope xmln:env = "http://abc.ca">
    <env:Header> 
      <mm7:TransactionID xmlns:mm7="http://def.ca"> Some Text Here </mm7:TransactionID>
    </env:Header>
  </env:Envelope>
```

The code I have is:

```
env_ns = {
  "xmlns:env" => "http://abc.ca"
}

mm7_ns = {
  "xmlns:mm7" => "http://def.ca"
}

env_header = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml['mm7'].TransactionID(mm7_ns) do
    "Some Text Here"
  end
end

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new { |xml|
  xml['env'].Envelope(env_ns) do
    xml.Header do
      env_header
    end
  end
}

puts env_header.to_xml
puts "----------------------"

puts builder.to_xml
```

However, the output is not as desired because the value "Some Text Here" did not go inside the mm7:TranactionID tag. The mm7 tag did not go inside the header tag. Also, the header tag did not go inside the envelope tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <mm7:TransactionID xmlns:mm7="http://def.ca"/>
-----------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://abc.ca">
   <env:Header/>
  </env:Envelope>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need 1 builder:

```
env_ns = {
  "xmlns:env" => "http://abc.ca"
}

mm7_ns = {
  "xmlns:mm7" => "http://def.ca"
}

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml['env'].Envelope(env_ns) do
    xml.Header do
      xml['mm7'].TransactionID(mm7_ns, "Some Text Here")
    end
  end
end

puts builder.to_xml

# will render the following:
# <?xml version="1.0"?>
# <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://abc.ca">
#   <env:Header>
#     <mm7:TransactionID xmlns:mm7="http://def.ca">Some Text Here</mm7:TransactionID>
#   </env:Header>
# </env:Envelope>
```